# Problem when querying the database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I do:

```
channel = session.query(Channel).options(eagerload("items")).filter(Channel.title == title)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

If I rid of `options(eagerload("items"))`, it's working properly.

Any idea??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just guessing, but do you have some `eagerload` variable somewhere that's a boolean? That could be the direct cause of it. If not, than it would be useful to get a little more from stacktrace and/or code.

Comment: Yes, it's that, I just realized I declare eagerload variable in some point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy filtering works with operator overloading on column objects. You are, however, not referencing the column object, but the value property of the table. So instead of

```
Channel.title == title
```

which is a 'bool' object, you need

```
Channel.c.title == title
```

which yields a SLQAlchemy specific object.